# Bialetti Moka Express Pot

Tags: storage, maintenance, home-roasting, brewing-process, identify-this

[image]

Hi all! I am a new owner of a Bialetti Moka Express Pot! I have only had this little guy for maybe a month, and I am noticing that the water chamber is starting to look like this. Does anyone have any advice on fixing this issue or what I should be doing differently?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning it? If so, what did you use?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an anecdotal answer, but it's coming from a friend that really cares that their aluminium moka pot stays in a prime condition as long as possible:

If you want to minimize visual changes in your moka pot, make sure to rinse it (do not use soap) right after use, wipe it with a dry cloth afterwards, and do not reassemble it until it's dry (as it will trap the remaining moisture in the chamber which causes the aluminium to oxidise, changing the colour). That should slow down the process significantly.